# How to parse datetime using Laravel on date and time?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, php-carbon

I have datetime string: `2016-11-01 15:04:19`

How I can get date and time separated?

Comment: Use it as a `Carbon` instance, that way you can access the date, time desperately (even the day, month, year, hours, minutes, and so on) [docs on carbon](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 Carbon format datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33405939/laravel-5-carbon-format-datetime)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do

```
 $model->created_at->format('Y-m-d');
```

to format a specific date. This solution will only work if your date is a Carbon instance. Or you can use Mutators to format a date by default and make it a Carbon instance if necessary.https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Answer (score 16):

Carbon comes with multiple `setters` and `getters`.

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters

If you have a datetime string and you want to use it with a `Carbon` instance you can do:

```
$date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2016-11-01 15:04:19');
```

Then you can do something like:

```
$date->format('Y-m-d')
$date->format('H:i:s')
```

That being said, if you are getting this datetime from an `Eloquent` model then you should look at @AlexeyMezenin or @Christophvh answer.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

if you try these,

```
$stringTime = '2016-11-01 15:04:19';

return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($stringTime));

return date('H:i:s', strtotime($stringTime));
```

And carbon also avail,

```
Carbon::parse();
```

[Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

[php date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

It is okay for you..

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 6):

If your date it Carbon object, you can do this:

```
$date->toTimeString(); // Will output 14:15:16.
$date->toDateString(); // Will output 1975-12-25.
$date->toFormattedDateString(); // Will output Dec 25, 1975.
```

If you store this date in DB and if it's not Carbon instance, use [date mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) which will convert date to istances of Carbon:

```
protected $dates = [
    'custom_date',
];
```

And if you're getting date from some other source, you can create an instance of Carbon and `parse()` the date:

```
Carbon::parse($custom_date);
```

After this you can use methods listed above.

Answer (score 0):

A Laravel model's serializeDate function can be used to change the date format for different date attributes. This method allows you to choose the format in which dates need to be formatted.

```
protected function serializeDate($date){
    return $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
```