# How to customize date format for multiple date attributes in Laravel Model?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel Model named CostingSheetFabric with several date attributes defined in the $dates property, such as customer_start_date, customer_cancel_date, earliest_start_date, and earliest_cancel_date. I'm looking to customize the date format for these attributes when they are retrieved from the database.

I've tried using the asDateTime method in my model like this:

This seems not work for my use case, but I wanted to seek advice from the community. Is using asDateTime a recommended approach for customizing the date format in Laravel models, especially when dealing with multiple date attributes?

```
protected function asDateTime($value)
{
    return parent::asDateTime($value)->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

following are not possible a model may have 35 date columns

```
protected $dates = [
    'custom_date',
];
```

```
 public function getStartDateAttribute($value)
 {
     return Carbon::parse($value)->format("Y-m-d");
 }
```

tired this but does not working

Comment: I assume that the method `asDateTime()` is something you have written, is that right?

Comment: OPTIONS: [How to parse datetime using Laravel on date and time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40375022/how-to-parse-datetime-using-laravel-on-date-and-time)

Comment: yes, but it does not affect on my code

Comment: @RiggsFolly there can be multiple fields on a model i want to change all at once

Comment: Then it would be rather useful to know what was actually coded in that method. Otherwise you are asking "How long is a piece of string" ... Difficult to answer as no where near enough information is provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serializeDate function in a Laravel model can be used to alter the date format for various date attributes. You can specify the format in which dates are serialized by using this method.

```
protected function serializeDate($date){
    return $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Comment: this code resolve the issue